# Weak Law of Large Numbers for non independent sequence

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I'm trying to tackle the following problem from Chung's "A Course in Probability Theory":

Consider a sequence of random variables $(X_n, n\geq 1)$, and let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ denote the sum of the first $n$ random variables. Then, if $\mathbb E[X_n^2]\to 0$, we have:

\begin{equation}
\frac{S_n - \mathbb E[S_n]}{n} \stackrel{\mathbb{P}}\to 0
\end{equation}

That is, we have convergence in probability.

This claim has been given a short proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671421/law-of-large-numbers-second-moment-tends-to-0-but-s-n-n-doesnt-converge-a-e), but I don't see why the argument checks out, since it apparently uses the fact that the $1$ norm is smaller than the $2$ norm, and I don't see why that would be the case.

So far, my approach was to try to center the sequence of random variables (considering $X_n - \mathbb E[X_n]$) and try to prove $L_2$ convergence, or try to show $L_1$ convergence directly, but I was not able to do so.

Comment: $\mathbb E[\lvert X\rvert] \leq \mathbb E[\lvert X\rvert^2]^{1/2} \mathbb E[1^2]^{1/2} = \mathbb E[\lvert X\rvert^2]^{1/2}$ is just Holder.

Comment: Oh great, thats true. Thanks. So we have not only convergence in probability, but also L1 convergence, right?

Comment: yes, $L^2$ convergence implies $L^1$ convergece (since the space has finite measure)

Comment: Ok, but is it right to say that we can prove $L^1$ convergence directly since $\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}[|S_n - \mathbb{E}[S_n]|]\leq \frac{2}{n}\sum_i \mathbb{E}[|X_i|]$ (by successive applications of the triangular inequality)?